# How to set connectionString of .NET web application with database in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, database, macos, docker

I am running Visual Studio in MAC OS. I have a web application developed in .NET. I want to attach this application with a database that I was able to configure and run using Docker in a localhost server.

If I were to work in Visual Basic (in windows) what I usually do to connect to the database is modify the "DefaultConnection" of the `Web.config` file:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=mypc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But in the case of MAC, as I am running the server in Docker, I don't know what should be the connection string. My question is how to find the string or what should I use as `connectionString` in this case where the database is in Docker.

Comment: I have MsSQL running in Docker and this is my example connection string: `Server=127.0.0.1,1433; Database=abc;User Id=user;Password=dummy_Pass123;`. So all in all, nothing special, the same as if you would have the db locally(if you ran the container exposing the port the db needs).

Comment: @Dinac23 Thank you for the answer. However when running my web app I get: Error 500 Application Exception `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`